# How to check if splitted column values is in another column?

Tags: python, join, pyspark, data-science

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have two dataframes A and B. I want to split column colA in dataframe A with a space and want to see if its splitted values are in colB in dataframe B and want to join them.

I wrote the following code for that:

```
A = A.join(B, array_contains(F.split(A.colA, " "), B.colB))
```

When I run this locally it works but in AWS Glue I get an error because this [wasnt fixed back then](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29627?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) It should be an exact match, not only a substring match like array_contains does this. Can someone show me an alternative way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expr` function for the join condition

```
A.alias('A').join(B.alias('B'), F.expr('array_contains(split(A.colA, " "), B.colB)'))
```